# NativeScript not getting the Set-Cookie

Tags: angular, http, nativescript, angular-http, angular-httpclient

I'm building an app in Nativescript but I have some strange behavior when doing the login functionality, as in the first login call that I did I get the 'Set-Cookie' header, but then I do logout and after that when I do the login again I'm not getting that header any more.

Below you have the login service:

```
_loginPost(url: string, params: any): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise<Response>((resolve, reject) => {
      const res = new Response();
      if (this.checkConnection()) {
        this.http.post(this.endpoint + url, params, {
    observe: "response",
    "Content-Type":  "application/json"
  }).toPromise().then((response: any) => {
            try {
                const cookie = response.headers.get("Set-Cookie");
                res.wasSuccess(cookie.slice(0, cookie.indexOf(";")).toString());
            } catch (error) {
              res.failed("ERROR");
            }
            resolve(res);
        }, (e) => {
          if (e && e.error) {
            if (e.status === 403) {
              res.failed("MUST_LOGOUT");
            } else {
              res.failed(e.error.cause);
            }
          } else {
            res.failed("ERROR");
          }
          resolve(res);
        });
      } else {
        res.failed("No Internet Conection");
        resolve(res);
      }
  });
  }
```

Below you have the images of both requests

First Request:
[image]

Second Request:
[image]

Comment: In your code you are looking for "Set-Cookie" and in your question you had mentioned "Get-Cookie", are you sure there is no typo in your code? Did you verify behaviour with any REST client, may be POSTMAN for instance. Also this seems to be dependent on your api, can you share the endpoint access, Or you may create stubs where we can see the actual issue?

Comment: Sorry, it's Set-Cookie always.. I will correct the typo in the post